# OrchardCMS Replacement Tokens for Query Results displaying HTML tags instead rendering them

Tags: replace, token, orchardcms

I am having problems understanding the token system for the output of query / projections.

If I leave the property as is it displays the text content with HTML formatting intact.

But I need to wrap it with a tag, the html tags get displayed as text.
Rewrite Results -> Rewrite output

```
<div class="collapse" id="toggle_{Content.Id}">
{Content.Fields.CaseStudy.ClientChallenge} </div>
```

I am trying to create a collapsible text area, I already have a button that hides/unhides the content.

Why is it displaying as text instead of rendering the tags properly.

I think this is because I don't know how replacement tokens work. 
Another example problem is up one level on the edit Layout, I want to set the item class to work-item {Category}, Category being the name/title of a property, which I am using for grouping.

Right above the projection: I want to include some html that lists all the Categorys in a ul i.e. data-filter=".experiential" I have tried things like: work-item {Category} and  work-item {Content.Fields.CaseStudy.Category}. Category is a "term" (?) from a taxonomy.

I feel like I am failing to understand how it all works.

Comment: What type of field is this?

Comment: (Text Field) Display Options set to HTML.

Comment: I think that's a bug: the text field should provide its value as a HtmlString when it's configured for HTML. I'd file a bug for this.

Comment: Your second question should be re-asked as a new question: it's never good to put more than one question at a time on SO.

Comment: Thank you so much, submitted an issue: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7355 not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: New SO ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250304/orchard-cms-query-raw-layout-level-access-to-properties In case you were interested in answering. :D

Answer (score 0):

Submitted as a bug https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7355
Will edit and post if it is fixed. In case anoyong else comes across this issue.